# Get proper response from http call, not exception

Tags: c#, .net, http

Here is code I use to POST into RESTful web service. My problem is with a last line. 
For example, my server can reply with different messages and same code. 
Now, unless I get 200 OK I just get exception on last line.

I'd like to have better access to response header, etc no matter what code I got. How is that possible?

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(Options.DitatServerUri + Options.DitatAccountId + "/integration/trip") as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request == null) return false;

            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Options.DitatLoginName + ":" + Options.DitatPassword)));
            request.Method = "POST";

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var serializedData = serializer.Serialize(trip);

            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedData);

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            var os = request.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            os.Close();

            var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Example: I get WebException "Invalid Operation" but server actually send message with error explanation.

Comment: What exception? Did you read [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx)?

Comment: It returns `WebException`. Good enough I guess - I get HTTP code, but I want to read headers, etc. I'm not complaining about other exceptions. I just want to have more control over response when server actually responded

Comment: For headers, check `WebException.Response.Headers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what Jon said above in the comments, the exception thrown for a bad status code is most likely a `WebException`, which has Response and Status properties, as per [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx).  Therefore, you can get the response via:

```
WebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    response = ex.Response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was brain fart.. I didn't realize I can dig down into exception.

Answer (score 1):

Why not catch the exception and handle it appropriately?

```
try 
{
    var response = request.GetResponse(); 
}
catch (WebException webEx) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response).StatusDescription);
}
```